# Whether a `.wim` file is a disk's all copy? contains all the partitions of a disk?

Tags: windows, wim

We know the `WIM` is Windows Imaging Format,

such as we know the `install.wim`, is it mean all of a disk's copy?

if the disk have four partitions, will the `install.wim` contains all the four partitions and the contents of them?

---

I mean whether a `.wim` file is a disk's all copy? contains all the partitions of a disk?

---

the other question is how can `install.wim` file can install a Windows OS? is there any install programs in it?

Comment: The answer is No. You already got it in your other question.